# How can I add custom data to OpenStreetMap data?

Tags: openstreetmap

How can I add custom data to OpenStreetMap data?

We have some internal data sets, some in MapInfo format, some just Excel spreadsheets with post codes.

What we'd like to do is overlap our data on top of the OpenStreetMap data in a public facing web application, preferably from the raw data on our internal servers, but we could do a nightly build of a data layer for loading onto a hosting web site/server

Comment: Web or desktop? Which software/libraries?

Comment: Be sure to read OSM's [legal FAQ](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ) regarding produced works, collective databases and derivative databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WEB
If you are working on the web, you can use Mapbox studio, leaflet.js or cartodb.com.

The main issue to start with is converting your data too a more web oriented format. You can probably export to .json from mapinfo (mapinfo plugin here http://communitydownloads.pbinsight.com/code-exchange/download/mapinfo2leaflet/ or online converter here http://converter.mygeodata.eu/). For xlsx, I'm assuming it is geographic data with x, y. If so, I would either bring into mapinfo to export as json or use a csv to json converter (http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm.).

If you have web knowledge javascript & html, you can use leaflet.js to build a web mapping application. If you want a more software-oriented solution, you can use Mapbox Studio to create the map. https://www.mapbox.com/help/getting-started-mapbox-studio-1/. Looks like you can import csv or zipped shapefiles to. So you probably can avoid converting to json. After working in Mapbox, you will have a basemap which you can share and look at, look at 'Share URL' on this link https://www.mapbox.com/help/getting-started-mapbox-studio-3/ or you can use the javscript libraries to present the maps in a web page (mapbox-gl.js or leaflet.js).

The other thing to look out for is map projection. Convert your data to Web Mercator because that is what most web maps use. http://epsg.io/3857

If this seems complicated, I would just start by searching for leaflet or mapbox tutorials.

On desktop (MapInfo, QGIS, ArcGIS) you can download excerpts of OSM and import to overlay with your data.
Downloads can be found at various sites
https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts
http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america.html

Comment: Can you clarify how you "use" them for working on the web